# Big O time complexity of O(sqrt(n)) + O(n^2) is O(n)?

Tags: big-o

I am studying the Big O notation and I am trying to understand if a function that has an O(sqrt(n)) part and an O(n^2) is approximated by O(n) or O(n^2).

Comment: It being O(n) would imply that the work somehow got less once you added a second step that took O(sqrt(n)). That's obviously not true

Answer (score 0):

O(n<sup>2</sup>).

For sufficiently large n, in the expression n<sup>2</sup> + sqrt(n), the n<sup>2</sup> component will be much larger than sqrt(n).

A more mathematically precise way of putting that is that there exists two constants you can multiply n<sup>2</sup> by to bound the function n<sup>2</sup> + sqrt(n) from above and below.

You can use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1*n%5E2+%3C+%28n%5E2%2Bsqrt%28n%29%29+%3C+2*n%5E2) to show this. Here, for n > 1, constants of 1 and 2 bound the function.